# Unable to Create Wildcard Let's Encrypt using ACME DNS01 Challenge provider in Kubernetes

Tags: dns, kubernetes, lets-encrypt, certbot

I am trying to create wildcard let's encrypt SSL certificate in Kubernetes. I tried the the ACME-DNS DNS01 challenge and it not creating the SSL certificates.

`Error preparing issuer for certificate default/wildcard-test-tk: ACME server does not allow selected challenge type or no provider is configured for domain "domtest.tk"`

I have referred this [link](http://docs.cert-manager.io/en/master/reference/issuers/acme/dns01/acme-dns.html) and used this [acme-dns](https://auth.acme-dns.io/register) for creating credentials to verify the domain authority.

Comment: Can you share Kubernetes object configs for `Certificate` and `ClusterIssuer`?

Comment: This is the `Issuer` condig
```apiVersion: certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: Issuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-testdom-prod
  namespace: default
spec:
  acme:
    email: myemail@mydomain.com
    server: "https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-test-prod
      dns01:
        providers:
        - name: dns-wildcard
          acmedns:
            host: https://auth.acme-dns.io
            accountSecretRef:
              name: acme-test-dns
              key: acmedns.json```

Comment: And this is the `Certificate` config


```apiVersion: certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
 name: wildcard-test-tk
 namespace: default
spec:
 secretName: wildcard-test-tk-tls
 issuerRef:
   name: letsencrypt-testdom-prod
   kind: Issuer
 dnsNames:
   - '*.testdom.tk'
 acme:
   config:
     - dns01:
         provider: dns-wildcard
       domains:
         - '*.testdom.tk' ```

Comment: The issue corresponds to the different domain `domtest.tk` against `testdom.tk` that you've declared. Have you tried to add `domtest.tk` domain to your configuration?

Comment: It is the typo when replacing the real domain.

Comment: Check `cert-manager` logs for any other related issues, also try to replace Issuer URL with https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory.

Comment: @Basheer.O, can you add `Certificate` and `ClusterIssuer` objects to the original post? Are you using an Ingress service? How did you re-deploy? Are you using TravisCI? GCP?